# Flatten binary tree to linked list

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list, time-limit-exceeded, tree

I'm trying to flatten a binary tree into a linked list.

I have a working, correct solution:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
  class TreeNode:
      def __init__(self, x):
          self.val = x
          self.left = None
          self.right = None


def insert(root, node):
    if root.right is None:
        root.right = node 
        return None 
    else:
        insert(root.right, node)
class Solution:
    def flatten(self, root: TreeNode) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify root in-place instead.
        """
        if root is None:
            return None 
        if root.left is None and root.right is None:
            return root 
        left = self.flatten(root.left)
        right = self.flatten(root.right)
        root.left = None
        if left:
            root.right = left 
            insert(root.right, right)
        else:
            root.right = right
        return root
```

I'm not certain, but I think the time complexity is \$O(n^2)\$. How do I make it run faster? Specifically, how do I modify it so that it runs in optimal time complexity (linear time)?

Comment: Not enough for a review, but note you shouldn't be returning anything ("Do not return anything, modify root in-place instead.", `-> None:`), yet you are (`return root`).

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say that it isn't working, but it's certainly not complete. Please show the source code for `TreeNode`.

Comment: Why is flatten in its own class called Solution?  Is this a requirement for some online test?  I'd think it makes more sense as a method on TreeNode if not a standalone function.

Comment: I've once tried it to, perhaps the answer could give you some insights: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226781/convert-a-binary-tree-to-doubly-linked-list

Comment: @bullseye The code works fine (especially now that the class was uncommented). Also, I believe you know you can't VTC if you don't have 3k rep

Comment: @Turksarama That's a dumb requirement for Leetcode challenges (https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-binary-tree-to-linked-list/).

Answer (score 2):

### Encapsulating the wrong things

`insert` and `flatten` should be methods on `TreeNode`. `Solution` doesn't particularly need to exist as a class. Those two methods can assume that `self` is the root.

### Return types

As @Carcigenicate suggested: what do you return from `flatten`? Probably the return type hint should be changed to `TreeNode`, and you should modify your comment to describe the circumstances under which `None` will or won't be returned.

Comment: I'll just note, this is a Leetcode challenge, which necessitates the useless `Solution`  class and the method signature requirements and the included docstring. I agree with your suggestions, but I think Leetcode set them off on the wrong foot here. https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-binary-tree-to-linked-list/